# How to deploy an Expo/React Native app to iOS Device from Xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I'm somewhat new to react native and expo but I've been trying to deploy a test version to my phone but can't figure out how to get it to build.

For some extra context, I built most of it in Expo and then ejected it (yes I know this isn't the best choice but I liked the features Expo provided). I ejected it because I needed NFC support which isn't currently supported in Expo so I added that in manually in Xcode after I ejected.

When I open the Xcode workspace and try to deploy it to my phone I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to connect to the packager server. If you did not start this build by running 'react-native run-android', you can start the packager manually by running 'react-native start' in the project directory. (Error: Request to packager server failed: 500)
    at /Users/user/Downloads/honorProj-reactNatveFinal/honorProj/reactNative/ethelontisApp/node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/createManifest.js:40:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I know it says run `react-native start` in the project directory (although I'm not entirely what the `at /Users/...` is refering too) but what really threw me was that it mentioned `react-native run-android` which doesn't seem like it should be related at all.

Lastly I'm completely and utterly lost with what `Command PhaseScriptExecution` is.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the exact same issue. So I just completed the set up the android development first.

But before doing anything, follow the below steps, it may solves the problem.

**Step-1**: Open terminal and navigate to your project directory example: cd Your project path.

**Step-2**: Type npx react-native start

**Step-3**: If you get any error like "error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081"

Then follow step-4 to 6:

**Step-4** : type sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 // You will get PID from here

**Step-5**: type kill -9 PIDvalue

**Step-6**: Repeat the step 2 and 3 once again

If you will not get any error in step- 2 then type npx react-native run-android 
and check if there is any error. If yes, then you have to [set up the android development first](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) to make it working - (As of now I found this way, but not sure if anyone can find any better way).

Else Open the code using xcode then clean the build and also clean the build folder then try to run.

Thanks, Hope it will help.

Comment: Yeah turns out the issue was really just starting the packager.